# python get substring from regex

Tags: python, regex, substring

I want to extract a substring from a string, which is conform to a certain regex. The regex is:

`(\[\s*(\d)+ byte(s)?\s*\](\s*|\d|[A-F]|[a-f])+)`

Which effectively means that all of these strings get accepted:

```
[4 bytes] 66 74 79 70 33 67 70 35
[ 4 bytes ] 66 74 79 70 33 67 70 35
[1 byte] 66 74 79 70 33 67 70 35
```

I want to extract only the amount of bytes (just the number) from this string. I thought of doing this with `re.search`, but I'm not sure if that will work. What would be the cleanest and most performant way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`match.group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) to get the groups your regular expression defines:

```
import re

s = """[4 bytes] 66 74 79 70 33 67 70 35
[ 4 bytes ] 66 74 79 70 33 67 70 35
[1 byte] 66 74 79 70 33 67 70 35"""
r = re.compile(r"(\[\s*(\d)+ byte(s)?\s*\](\s*|\d|[A-F]|[a-f])+)")

for line in s.split("\n"):
    m = r.match(line)
    if m:
        print(m.group(2))
```

The first group matches `[4 bytes]`, the second only `4`.

Output:

```
4
4
1
```

Comment: OP only wants the number of bytes!

Comment: @pidgey `(\s*|\d|[A-F]|[a-f])+` should be rewritten as `[\s\dA-Fa-f]+` seeing as you don't care about what it captures.

Comment: @nhahtdh Please comment the question about the regex.

Comment: @Tichodroma: I leave it here so that you can consider to include it in your answer. You can leave it alone if you don't want to. I have already pinged the OP in my comment.